# My plugin got sourced first before init.lua

Tags: vimscript, neovim, plugin-system

I make a [colorscheme plugin](https://github.com/manungsa/nvim-colors) with vimscript (the code sucks, as I've never write a plugin before), there it checks if a global var exist or not.

```
" nvim-colors/colors/kalm.vim
...
if !exists('g:kalm_transparent_bg')
    let g:kalm_transparent_bg = 0
endif

if g:kalm_transparent_bg == 1
    hi Normal ctermbg=black ctermfg=white guifg=lightgray
else
    hi Normal ctermbg=black ctermfg=white guibg=#080a0c guifg=lightgray
endif
...
```

The problem is, it seems that this plugin got sourced first before my init.lua which contains the configuration line.

```
" $HOME/.config/init.lua
vim.cmd [[
    colorscheme kalm
    let g:kalm_transparent_bg = 1
]]
```

I checked it with `--startuptime` flag passed to neovim, here's the output:

```
...
004.238  000.456  000.456: sourcing /home/galih/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/vendor/start/nvim-colors/colors/kalm.vim
...
017.180  014.002  003.681: sourcing /home/username/.config/nvim/init.lua
...
```

I want so that I can write all the config option inside init.lua, and got it checked inside the plugin file easily.
Do you have any idea about how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
colorscheme kalm
```

Will source your colorscheme file.  The color scheme is switched to immediately, this is a command not a setting.

```
let g:kalm_transparent_bg = 1
colorscheme kalm
```